# Upload progress bar in Catalyst app

Tags: jquery, file-upload, catalyst

For my Catalyst project (FastCGI under Apache2), I would like to have an upload progress bar. The form is created with HTML::FormHandler and contains several text fields and a file upload input (it is not a pure file uploader).

So far, I tried 1) [Catalyst::Plugin::UploadProgress](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Plugin-UploadProgress-0.06/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/UploadProgress.pm) and 2) [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) - without success. Form submission and file upload still works, but with 1) no progress bar is visible and with 2) the progress bar stays at 0%.

I followed the docs as close as possible. What am I missing? Should these solutions work with Catalyst out of the box?

**Attempt 1) Catalyst::Plugin::UploadProgress**

```
<head>
    <link href="/static/css/progress.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/run/start" method="post" onsubmit="return startEmbeddedProgressBar(this)">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="date" name="date" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<div id="progress"></div>

<script src="/static/js/progress.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/progress.jmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Attempt 2) jQuery Form Plugin**

```
<head>
    <link href="/static/css/progress.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/run/start" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="date" name="date" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the second solution with jQuery Form Plugin works like charm now.
The browser console showed the error `ajaxForm is not a function`. The problem was probably that github doesn't want to be a CDN. After serving `jquery.form.js` locally the problem was solved.